# Forcing code to run sequentially in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, sockets, socket.io

In a `Angular.js` and `Socket.io` App, I want to show a loading before sending an image via `Socket.io`. I write this code:

When a button clicked this code runs, first i want to run `startLoading` function and after that I want to send image:

```
$scope.startLoading(function(){
      $scope.socket.emit('sendImg', {
            data: $scope.newImg,
      });
});
```

and this is my `startLoading` function:

```
$scope.startLoading = function (callback) {
    //DO SOME STUFF LIKE ENABLING LOADING ANIMATION
    $scope.animation =true; //binded to UI
    $scope.errors = false; //binded to UI

    callback(); //it seems this code runs before above lines
};
```

But it seems `callback()` line runs before first two lines and because of that, my loading appears after sending of image to the server! why? i change callback line to a timeout like this and it works fine but is this a good solution? i dont think! what i have to do for a standard code?

```
$scope.startLoading = function (callback) {
    //DO SOME STUFF LIKE ENABLING LOADING ANIMATION
    $scope.animation =true; //binded to UI
    $scope.errors = false; //binded to UI

    $timeout(function(){callback();}, 1000);
};
```

Actually, code runs sequentially but calling callback and sending image freezes page and because of that, my loading appears after freezing ends. but i need before freezing, loading starts

Comment: Put a breakpoint at the animation line to see when exactly the callback is being called.

Comment: @Victory: you know, code runs sequentially but calling callback and sending image freezes page and because of that, my loading appears after freezing ends. but i need before freezing, loading starts

Comment: How are animation and errors variables being used?

Comment: @GPicazo: as i write in the code, they are angular variables and making a variable true, changes the UI

Comment: Shouldn't it be $scope.animation and $scope.errors? If they are set later, then that is the reason you don't see what you want.

Comment: @Fcoder: so you're only _observing the effect_ of changing these variables (the UI change) after `callback()`. The lines are executed sequentially, there is no magic here... but the UI will only be updated after your function finishes. Simply setting a variable doesn't trigger anything in Angular immediately. This is why the order of things appears correct when you use `$timeout`.

Comment: @pdenes: what i have to do now?

Comment: @Fcoder: difficult to tell without knowing more details. E.g. how exactly those variables affect the UI (there must be some other piece of code that references those variables, as GPicazo said they are not part of the $scope...), what exactly you want to achieve, etc. Your solution with $timeout may even be fine...

Comment: @pdenes: that vaeiables has $scope before them but i forget to write here, sorry. for example if $scope.animation =true; , an ng-if inside html checks that value and if its true, then show a loading div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code really does run sequentially, but the first two lines don't change the UI immediately.

When you assign some value to a scope variable, it's just that, a variable assignment. It doesn't trigger any events. Angular will only update the UI later, when it evaluates the bindings and finds the change. So here is what happens:

```
$scope.startLoading = function (callback) {

    // Presumably this is called from some event from Angular, 
    // so all this is run in an $apply, in an Angular "context".
    // But this is still "plain" javascript, so the next two lines
    // are just plain variable assignments.

    $scope.animation =true;
    $scope.errors = false;

    callback();  // This function does its thing, then returns

    // When this function returns, Angular will evaluate all of its
    // bindings, will find that the above values have changed,
    // and will update the DOM.
};
```

For details, see the "Integration with the browser event loop" section in the [dev guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope).

What you want is to ensure that the DOM is updated *before* your callback runs. I think there is nothing wrong with using `$timeout` for this.
There might be a better/nicer way, but I haven't found it yet...

So it would become something like this:

```
$scope.startLoading = function (callback) {
    $scope.animation =true;  // at this point, these are just
    $scope.errors = false;   // plain variable assignments

    $timeout(callback);  // schedule callback to run later

    // After this returns, Angular will evaluate its bindings,
    // and update the DOM, so if $scope.animation and $scope.errors
    // are bound to something, they can trigger some visible change.

    // callback will be called in the next $digest cycle, so _after_
    // the DOM has been updated
};
```

(There is no need to specify a value for the timeout if you only want to run it in the next "tick". Also, there is no need to wrap callback, it can be directly passed to `$timeout`.)

Hope this helps!